# How to get Shopify merchandiseId?

Tags: graphql, postman, shopify, shopify-app

[image: This is the Screenshot of the API I'm trying to use]

I just need to know that how and where can I get this merchandiseId?

Answer (score 2):

It's just the product variant id you want to add.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).